# Using tox and pyproject.toml

Tags: python, tox, pyproject.toml

I am trying to switch a project from using `setup.py` to PEP518. I have written the following minimal `pyproject.toml`:

```toml
[build-system]
requires = ["cython", "setuptools", "wheel", "oldest-supported-numpy"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

I need some custom installation logic relying on `setup.py`, so I cannot currently switch to a purely declarative setting.

Notably, my `setup.py` contains an `import numpy` which I use to add `numpy.get_include()` to the includes of an extension. I can build the sdist / wheel using `python -m build`, which works as intended (providing a build environment by installing the dependencies before calling into `setup.py`)

I also have a test suite which I run using `tox`. However, when I run `tox` in my project I see the following error:

```
GLOB sdist-make: /project/setup.py
ERROR: invocation failed (exit code 1), logfile: /project/.tox/log/GLOB-0.log
...
File "/project/setup.py", ...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

So, per default `tox` does *not* install the build dependencies before building the sdist to be used for testing later, causing everything to fail.

Therefore, as suggested in the tox [example](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/example/package.html), I added

```ini
[tox]
isolated_build = True

[testenv]
commands = pytest
```

to the top of `tox.ini`, which *should* enable the isolated build. However, when I then execute `tox` now, all I get is

```
___ summary ___
  congratulations :)
```

so nothing is actually built / tested (as opposed to a non-isolated build with `numpy` installed). Is this the expected behavior? How can I actually build and run tests in an isolated environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so as it turns out, isolated builds require an `envlist` like this to work properly (as opposed to the ordinary one which defaults to using the current python environment):

```toml
[tox]
isolated_build = True
envlist = py310
```